# What do you call a person who doesn't like/hates traveling?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> Speaker A: Should we invite Mark to the trip?
>
> Speaker B: Nah, he's a [...]

Comment: "Smart" may be the word you're looking for.

Comment: Sometimes people call such a person "a stick in the mud" or "a stick-in-the-mud"

Comment: Some variant on **provincial** could fit in here as well: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/provincialism

Comment: He's a [*Hesita*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hestia)--an allusion to the Greek goddess of hearth and home.

Comment: If the aversion to travel specifically involves travel to and in foreign lands, the term _xenophobe_ (one who fears or dislikes foreign things) is relevant; of course "foreign" is a relative concept: To some New Yorkers, Texas is quite foreign; and to some Texans, New York is.

Comment: Another way to fill in the blank in Speaker B's sentence is with a phrase like "sessile life form," where _sessile_ means (according to Merriam-Webster) "permanently attached or established : not free to move about."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can call that person a *homebody*.

Comment: Please provide reliable evidence to support your answer. Links to dictionaries are the most basic and easiest way to do provide useful information to users.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not a single word, but:

***stay-at-home person***

> Christian Living Seven Days a Week - Page 121 Jack Mcinturff - 2007
>
> a traveler, then this will not work unless the traveler becomes a
>   person that is perfectly content to stay home or travel less, or **the
>   stay-at-home person learns to enjoy traveling.**

Answer (score 0):

A [coach potato](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/couch+potato)  may suggest the idea:

> - (n) a lazy person whose recreation consists chiefly of watching television and videos. (Collins Dict.)
> - (n) a person whose leisure time is spent watching television. (Webster's College Dict.)

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: A coach potato would be running a sports team of tubers. I think you mean "couch potato."  That being said, a couch potato just doesn't exert much energy; it's not really about not traveling.

Answer (score 0):

***"Landlubber"*** (derived from "land-lover") refers to someone who is unwilling to travel by boat; but I use it to describe my dislike of flying also - after all, technically I'd be off the land. (US)

Answer (score 0):

"Couch potato" may be a variant

Comment: I think "couch potato" tends to have a stronger connotation. More than someone who doesn't like to travel, this person doesn't even like to leave the house and won't make an effort to help clean the house.

Answer (score 0):

If you want stronger words that emphasize the aversion to traveling (and not just someone who enjoy staying home); you can consider the adjectives ***travel-averse*** or ***travel-phobic***. They might not be a fit or the usual fit to your examples but you can use in other ways.

> Travel aversion, not to be confused with *hodophobia*, is a condition experienced by people that dislike or disapprove traveling. People who abstain from travel may see traveling more as a chore than as a leisure.
>
> **Travel-averse people** feel well enough at home, and do not see the point in traveling.
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_aversion)

An example with *travel-phobic*:

> You need to ask yourself a number of questions to see if you are **travel-phobic.** For example, when you pack to go on vacation, do you stress about it? Do you always underpack or overpack? Do you hate flying? Do you hate to drive? Do you mind sleeping in hotel rooms for a long period of time?...
>
> *The Vault College Career Bible* By Vault Editors

***Hodophobia***, mentioned earlier, is the irrational and intense fear of travel. This might be too strong for your context. *Hodophobic* is someone who has hodophobia.

Comment: In the dialogue provided by the OP the term *hodophobia* just doesn't fit. Is this a word you were already familiar with or did you do some research beforehand? Any ordinary person will only respond: *Whaaat*? If it's too extreme a term then why suggest it? The term *travel phobic* is easily comprehensible, but it is not idiomatic, again, the OP wants a term that fits within a natural dialogue. *Homebody*, *stay-at-home*, or *couch potato* fulfills this need IMO.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Thanks. I explained also why it might not fit to the example, I'm not just throwing words around without explanation. This answers the general question in detail. I knew about "homebody" (and I could mention as an additional answer if it wasn't given) and it might be a fit for the example but it doesn't mean who dislikes traveling. Actually, none of the other words given mean that and some of them are just general words that happen to fit to the example sentence.

Comment: A *homebody* is exactly someone who never wants to go anywhere, a person who prefers to sit home in front of the telly in his/her slippers, a cup of tea and a packet of crisps/chips. You don't have to be suffering from a phobia to not like travelling, this isn't agoraphobia.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two possible words for this. One is "Homevert" (from Home+Introvert) and another is "Stay-gnate" (variations Stay-gnant, Stay-Gnator), combination of Stay and stagnant/stagnate. I guess we'll see if these catch-on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).